# Reading Time from String into "Morning", "Afternoon", "Evening", "night"

Tags: java

So I got problem, the input is a String of time 04:30, if 04.01 untill 11 the output  "Morning", 11.01-15 the output is "Afternoon", 15.01-18.30 "evening", and 18.31-4 is "Night". Which part im doing wrong.

Here's my code:

```java
import java.util.*;

public class Solution {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        String input = in.next();
        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm");
        Date d = dateFormat.parse(input);
            
        if (d > 4 || d <= 11) {
            System.out.println("Morning");
        } else if (d > 11 || d <= 15) {
            System.out.println("Afternoon");
        } else if (d > 15 || d <= 18.3) {
            System.out.println("Evening");
        } else if (d > 18.3 || d <= 4) {
            System.out.println("Night");
        }            
    }
}
```

Comment: Create a java.time.LocalTime objects and use the comparison methods available in the API.

Comment: Use `&&` instead of `||`.

Comment: Never use `Date` and `SimpleDateFormat`. These terrible classes were years ago supplanted by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one solution:

```
    DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm");
    LocalTime time = LocalTime.parse(input, fmt);
    int d = 100*time.getHour() + time.getMinute();

    if (d <= 400 || d > 1830) {
        System.out.println("Night");
    } else if (d <= 1100) {
        System.out.println("Morning");
    } else if (d <= 1500) {
        System.out.println("Afternoon");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Evening");
    }
```

But you don't need to convert the input string into a date/time.

Answer (score 1):

### *Which part im doing wrong?*

1. You are trying to compare objects using operators for primitives
2. Your pattern for parsing the time of day should be `HH:mm` instead of `hh:mm`

---

### Alternative: `java.time`

Since this is all about the time of day disregarding day, month, year (and even seconds or smaller units), you can use a class designed for exactly that, a `java.time.LocalTime`.

Here's a readable example:

```java
/**
 * Determines the prosaic daytime (Morining, Afternoon, Evening, Night) of
 * the time of day passed as {@code String}.
 * 
 * @param timeOfDay time of day in 24h format
 * @return prosaic daytime
 */
public static String dayTime(String timeOfDay) {
    // parse the input without applying a formatter
    LocalTime localTime = LocalTime.parse(timeOfDay);
    // define the border values
    LocalTime eleven = LocalTime.of(11, 0);
    LocalTime four = LocalTime.of(4, 0);
    LocalTime fifteen = LocalTime.of(15, 0);
    LocalTime eighteenThirty = LocalTime.of(18, 30);
    
    // check if the time is after four and either before or exactly eleven
    if (localTime.isAfter(four) &&
            (localTime.isBefore(eleven) || localTime.equals(eleven)))
        return "Morning";
    // check if the time is after eleven and either before or exactly fifteen
    else if (localTime.isAfter(eleven) &&
            (localTime.isBefore(fifteen) || localTime.equals(fifteen)))
        return "Afternoon";
    // check if the time is after fifteen and either before or exactly eighteen thirty
    else if (localTime.isAfter(fifteen) &&
            (localTime.isBefore(eighteenThirty) || localTime.equals(eighteenThirty)))
        return "Evening";
    // otherwise it's night
    else return "Night";
}
```

Test it with some significant values:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    List<String> times = List.of(
                // morining
                "04:01", "10:59", "11:00",
                // afternoon
                "11:01", "14:59", "15:00",
                // evening
                "15:01", "18:29", "18:30",
                // night
                "18:31", "03:59", "04:00"
            );
    
    times.forEach(
            time -> System.out.println(
                    String.format("%s is in the %s", 
                                    time, dayTime(time))));
}
```

Output:

```
04:01 is in the Morning
10:59 is in the Morning
11:00 is in the Morning
11:01 is in the Afternoon
14:59 is in the Afternoon
15:00 is in the Afternoon
15:01 is in the Evening
18:29 is in the Evening
18:30 is in the Evening
18:31 is in the Night
03:59 is in the Night
04:00 is in the Night
```

Answer (score 1):

## Use `LocalTime#isBefore` for brevity

Other Answers appear to be correct, but could be shorter.

For one thing, your input string complies with the [ISO 8601](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format of strings, assuming such inputs use 24-hour clock (00-23).  If so, then your formatting pattern is incorrect, where the `hh` should be uppercase `HH`. And, more importantly, you need not specify any formatting pattern if parsing with `LocalTime`. The *java.time* classes use standard ISO 8601 formats by default when parsing/generating text.

```
LocalTime lt = LocalTime.parse( "23:51" ) ;
```

We can drop the combined predicates, eliminating the `&&`, by making five tests rather than four. The tests compare times with a call to [`LocalTime#isBefore`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalTime.html#of(int,int)). Notice how both the first *and* last tests return “Night”.

```java
if( lt.isBefore( LocalTime.of( 4 , 0 ) ) ) { return "Night" ; }
else if( lt.isBefore( LocalTime.of( 11 , 0 ) ) ) { return "Morning" ; }
else if( lt.isBefore( LocalTime.of( 15 , 00 ) ) ) { return "Afternoon" ; }
else if( lt.isBefore( LocalTime.of( 18 , 30 ) ) ) { return "Evening" ; }
else { return "Night" ; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you comparison is done on Hours and minutes. Use a If...Else on hour and minute value can become heavy.

Try this instead :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        try (Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in)) {
                String input = in.next();
                
                LocalTime time = LocalTime.parse(input+":00.0");
                
                if ( time.isAfter(LocalTime.parse("04:00:00.0")) && time.isBefore(LocalTime.parse("11:01:00.0"))){
                        System.out.println("Morning");
                }
                else if ( time.isAfter(LocalTime.parse("11:00:00.0")) && time.isBefore(LocalTime.parse("15:00:00.0"))){
                        System.out.println("Afternoon");
                }else if ( time.isAfter(LocalTime.parse("15:00:00.0")) && time.isBefore(LocalTime.parse("18:30:00.0"))){
                        System.out.println("Evening");
                }else{
                        System.out.println("Night");
                }
                
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Try This:

### Possibility : 1

```
import java.util.*;

public class JimRaynor {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        String input = in.next();
        String[] x = input.split(":");

        int hour = Integer.parseInt(x[0]);
        int minute = Integer.parseInt(x[1]);

        if (hour > 4 && hour <= 11)
            System.out.println("Morning");
        else if (hour > 11 && hour <= 15)
            System.out.println("Afternoon");
        else if (hour > 15 && hour <= 18 && minute <= 3)
            System.out.println("Evening");
        else
            System.out.println("Night");
    }
}
```

### O/P:-

```
12:03
Afternoon
```

### Possibility : 2

```
import java.time.LocalTime;
import java.util.*;

public class JimRaynor {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        String input = in.next();
        String[] x = input.split(":");

        LocalTime time = LocalTime.of(Integer.parseInt(x[0]), Integer.parseInt(x[1]));

        int hour = time.getHour();
        int minute = time.getMinute();

        if (hour > 4 && hour <= 11)
            System.out.println("Morning");
        else if (hour > 11 && hour <= 15)
            System.out.println("Afternoon");
        else if (hour > 15 && hour <= 18 && minute <= 3)
            System.out.println("Evening");
        else
            System.out.println("Night");
    }
}
```

### O/P:-

```
12:03
Afternoon
```